# How can implement a procedure in ESQL (an internal procedure) from Oracle database

Tags: oracle, plsqldeveloper, embedded-sql

I create a store procedure in Oracle db that insert Customer to my Table

this is my code :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE THP.INSERT_CUSTOMER(

     P_CUSTNAME          IN       VARCHAR2,
     P_CUSTLAST          IN       VARCHAR2,
     P_CUSTFATHER        IN       VARCHAR2,
     P_NATIONNO          IN       NUMBER,
     P_BIRTHDAY          IN       VARCHAR2,
     P_BIRHTPLACE        IN       VARCHAR2,
     P_EMAIL             IN       VARCHAR2,
     P_CUSTENAME         IN       VARCHAR2,
     P_CUSTELAST         IN       VARCHAR2,
     P_OWNID             IN       NUMBER,
     P_CUSTTYPEID        IN       NUMBER,
     P_GENDERID          IN       NUMBER,
     P_BILLSTID          IN       NUMBER,
     P_BILLSPID          IN       NUMBER,
     P_IDNO              IN       varchar2,



     RESULT OUT INTEGER) IS
     CNT NUMBER;

BEGIN
     RESULT := 1;
     CNT := 0;
     SELECT COUNT(1) INTO CNT FROM THP.TBCUSTOMER WHERE NATIONNO=P_NATIONNO ;

     IF CNT=1 THEN  

         COMMIT;
         RESULT := 1;  --IF  RECORD is EXIST

     ELSE
        BEGIN  
            INSERT INTO TBCUSTOMER(CUSTID,CUSTNAME,CUSTLAST,CUSTFATHER,NATIONNO,BIRTHDAY,BIRHTPLACE,EMAIL,CUSTENAME,CUSTELAST,OWNID,CUSTTYPEID,GENDERID,BILLSTID,BILLSPID,IDNO)
            VALUES(CUSTID_SEQ.NEXTVAL,P_CUSTNAME,P_CUSTLAST,P_CUSTFATHER,P_NATIONNO,P_BIRTHDAY,P_BIRHTPLACE,P_EMAIL,P_CUSTENAME,P_CUSTELAST,P_OWNID,P_CUSTTYPEID,P_GENDERID,P_BILLSTID,P_BILLSPID,P_IDNO);
         COMMIT;
         RESULT :=0;  --IF INSERT NEW COLUMN

        END;  
     END IF;
END INSERT_CUSTOMER;
/
```

now I want use this procedure in ESQL and create it directly in ESQL not CALL it from Oracle database or other DB

would you please guide me a bout it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

General comments, not an answer ...

```
count(1)
```

count(1) = count(*), which is the standard form for "count the number of rows". count(1) has no advantages, so best to use count(*).

```
RESULT := 1
```

is redundant at the beginning of the procedure

```
CNT := 0
```

... also redundant. The variable name is not very meaningful, and might make people think of a rude word, so perhaps change it to rows_found.

Prefixing the arguments with P_ is not required. If you use one of them in a SQL statement and need to deconflict it from a database object name then prefix it with the procedure name, so you have:

```
WHERE NATIONNO= INSERT_CUSTOMER.NATIONNO
```

Is NATIONNO constrained to be unique in the customer table? If not, use:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
INTO   CNT
FROM   THP.TBCUSTOMER
WHERE  NATIONNO=INSERT_CUSTOMER.NATIONNO AND
       ROWNUM = 1;
```

(12g will introduce the LIMIT SQL syntax, by the way).

Commiting in a procedure is often held to be bad practice, as the procedure often becomes part of a longer business transaction (eg. inserting a new customer and address) and the commit should be controlled by the application code.

Upper case code is harder to read than lower case -- that's why direction signs on motorways are not uppercase.

The begin-end block for the insert is not required at all.

"birhtplace" is spelled wrong.

So I'd suggest that what you want to convert to ESQL is actually:

```
create or replace procedure thp.insert_customer(
    custname   in  varchar2,
    custlast   in  varchar2,
    custfather in  varchar2,
    nationno   in  number  ,
    birthday   in  varchar2,
    birhtplace in  varchar2,
    email      in  varchar2,
    custename  in  varchar2,
    custelast  in  varchar2,
    ownid      in  number  ,
    custtypeid in  number  ,
    genderid   in  number  ,
    billstid   in  number  ,
    billspid   in  number  ,
    idno       in  varchar2,
    result     out integer) is
rows_found number;
begin
    select count(*)
    into   rows_found
    from   thp.tbcustomer
    where  nationno=insert_customer.nationno;

    if rows_found = 1 then
        result := 1;
    else
        insert into
        tbcustomer(
            custid    ,
            custname  ,
            custlast  ,
            custfather,
            nationno  ,
            birthday  ,
            birthplace,
            email     ,
            custename ,
            custelast ,
            ownid     ,
            custtypeid,
            genderid  ,
            billstid  ,
            billspid  ,
            idno)
        values(
            custid_seq.nextval,
            custname  ,
            custlast  ,
            custfather,
            nationno  ,
            birthday  ,
            birthplace,
            email     ,
            custename ,
            custelast ,
            ownid     ,
            custtypeid,
            genderid  ,
            billstid  ,
            billspid  ,
            idno);

        result :=0;
     end if;
end insert_customer;
/
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your suggest dear
Now I want use this procedure directly at Web Sphere IBM Message Broker in ESQL (Compute node)

It's mean I select and insert into tables from database by Message Broker directly.
in past I call my procedure from database by ESQL but now I want create this procedure directly in ESQL and fetch my data...
I hope understand what I say
thanks...

Answer (score 0):

To call an external procedure via ESQL, you need to first declare the external function.

Do it as below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DoSomething (IN in1 CHARACTER, OUT out1 CHARACTER, OUT out2 CHARACTER)
    LANGUAGE DATABASE
    EXTERNAL NAME "DoSomething";
```

Now you can call this function from your ESQL function as below:

```
CALL DoSomething(in,out1,out2) IN Database.yourschema.yourDB;
```

P.S. The parameters you are passing must be compatible with the parameters of your stored procedure.